# Oxidation of cycloalkenes

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

Non-cyclic alkenes can be oxidized to carboxylic acids in presence of hot alkaline $\ce{KMnO4}$ and quenched with dilute $\ce{H2SO4}$ to form carboxylic acids. I suddenly got a thought. Can cycloalkenes be oxidized to form carboxylic acids? For example: can cyclohexene be oxidized to cyclohexanoic acid using the same conditions?

Comment: Your example sounds a bit weird to me. Using KMnO4 on alkenes can thansform the alkene function into a carbox acid function; but cyclohexene -> cyclohexanoic acid would actually _add_ a carbon atom on the cycle and put the carbox acid on that new carbon, it wouldn't really be similar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both ends of the alkene would be converted into a carboxylic acid functional group.

This would be a 'ring-opening' or 'permanganate cleavage' reaction and form adipic acid (hexanedioic).